# how to handler react route with vite-plugin-pages in 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, vite-plugin-pages

how to handler 404 page with react and vite with plugin vite-plugin-pages  [vite-plugin-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-pages).How to if file not exit in pages folder please redirect to 404 page in root folder pages??

[image]